# Siverlight setup issue

Tags: .net, silverlight, installation, xap

If I just deploy Siverlight application (eithre ASP.Net page or Html page uses XAP files) on Server, no need to develop. On Server side, do I need to install anything?

I have two scenarios,

1. Using Windows Server 2003;
2. Using Windows Server 2008.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to install anything, just deploy the files.  However, if you're on IIS 6 (such as the Server 2003 scenario), you do need to register the MIME type for XAP files (see [here](http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/archive/2008/07/07/registering-xap-mime-type-in-iis-6-0.aspx) for how to do so).  IIS7 should serve up XAP files by default.

Of course, you should also make sure that your server is correctly configured for ASP.NET, if necessary.  But that's not related to Silverlight.